# continuous update value of lable from NSObject Class

Tags: ios, objective-c

My song is playing from helper class (derived from NSObject) and I want to update the UI in the view, I know one method `PostNotification`. Is there another solution?

```
+(void)playRemoteFile:(NSString*)songURL {

    [[AFSoundManager sharedManager] startStreamingRemoteAudioFromURL:songURL andBlock:^(int percentage, CGFloat elapsedTime, CGFloat timeRemaining, NSError *error, BOOL finished) {

        if (!error) {
            // I want to update GUI here
            //_slider.value = percentage * 0.01;                
        } 
    }];
}
```

Comment: i am not aware with that can you please write code ? @Avi

Comment: Read about the delegate pattern and about blocks.  The suitability for your scenario should be obvious.

Comment: i tried best before posting Question here @Avi

Comment: Have `playRemoteFile` take a block parameter.  The block should be passed whatever data you need to update the UI.  At the point where you `NSLog()` the percent played, call the block with the information as parameters.

Comment: if you can add a bit code than it would help him a lot.

Comment: In Your case Delegate and KVC is more easy to use. Read from raywenderlich.com about delegate its easy. KVC is key Value Coding provides more advance features than Notification. With KVC can observe value of any property and when that value change you will get the method call.

Answer (score 2):

If you call playRemoteFile from viewController and it's possible to modify the playRemoteFile method.How about change it to:

```
+ (void)playRemoteFile:(NSString*)songURL andBlock:(void (^)(int percentage, CGFloat elapsedTime, CGFloat timeRemaining, NSError *error, BOOL finished))block {
    [[AFSoundManager sharedManager] startStreamingRemoteAudioFromURL:songURL andBlock:^(int percentage, CGFloat elapsedTime, CGFloat timeRemaining, NSError *error, BOOL finished) {
        block(percentage, elapsedTime, timeRemaining, error, finished)
    }];
}
```

Then in the viewController do this

```
[someObject playRemoteFile: songURL andBlock:^(int percentage, CGFloat elapsedTime, CGFloat timeRemaining, NSError *error, BOOL finished){
    if (!error) {
        // update GUI here
        //_slider.value = percentage * 0.01;                
    } 
}]
```

Comment: This is good but this will give me time where i call the method but not on Player screen i need time on player screen and i can change song from any class.so i had up voted instead of accept.

Comment: How can i implement KVO in this case?